# Is it possible to monitor .Net's intern pool size?

Tags: c#, .net, string-interning

I'm maintaining a legacy application that uses strings to lock values in a cache. It does so something like this:

```
object Cache(string key, Func<object> createObjToCache)
{
    object result = Get(key);
    if (result == null)
    {
        string internKey = string.Intern(key);
        lock (internKey) {
            result = Get(key);
            if (result == null)
            {
                result = createObjToCache();
                Add(key, result);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've two questions about this code. First is string.Intern() thread safe? Is it possible that two threads on two separate CPUs with two identical strings would return different references? If not is that a possible bottle neck, does string.Intern block?

Secondly I'm concerned that this application might be using a huge number of strings as keys. I'd like to be able to monitor the amount of memory that the intern pool uses to store all these strings, but I can't find a performance counter for this on .Net Memory. Is there one somewhere else?

**NOTE:**

I'm aware that this implementation sucks. However I need to make the case to management before re-writing what they see as a critical bit of code. Hence I could use facts and stats on exactly how bad it sucks rather than alternative solutions.

Also Get() and Add() are not in the original code. I've replaced the original code to keep this question simple. We can assume that Add() will not fail if it is called twice with the same or different keys.

Comment: For the string pool size you could look at perfmon, I don't know if it has a counter for it.

Comment: @gobes I did look at perfmon and couldn't find one. That might be because I couldn't find it though as there are hundreds to choose from.

Comment: Two threads both calling Add() at the same time for different keys is not a threading race??  String.Intern() does not cause a permanent memory leak??  Rip it out, use MemoryCache.

Comment: @HansPassant well that depends on the implementation of `Add()`.

Comment: @mjwills null counts as a cache miss. Not null is a cache hit. I've updated the question a bit to make it clearer why I ask.

Answer (score 3):

MSDN does not make any mention of thread-safety on `string.Intern`, so you're right in that it is very undefined what would happen if two threads called `Intern` for a **new** `key` at exactly the same time. I want to say "it'll probably work OK", but that isn't a guarantee. There *is no* guarantee AFAIK. The implementation is `extern`, so peeking at the implementation means looking at the runtime itself.

Frankly, there are *so many reasons* not to do this that it is hard to get excited about answering these specific questions. I'd be tempted to look at some kind of `Dictionary<string,object>` or `ThreadSafeDictionary<string,object>`  (where the `object` here is simply a `new object()` that I can use for the lock) - *without* all the issues related to `string.Intern`. Then I can a: query the size, b: discard it at whim, c: have parallel *isolated* containers, etc.

Comment: That was my first thought too, however I need to make the case to management for a re-write.

Comment: @MartinBrown yes, I understand the conflict; note that we're only talking about changing the implementation of one area, though

Answer (score 2):

> First is string.Intern() thread safe?

Unless something has changed (my info on this is quite old, and I'm not curious enough to take a look at the current implementation), yes. This however is about the only good thing with this idea.

Indeed, it's not fully a good thing. `string.Intern()` locks globally which is one of the things that can make it slow.

> Secondly I'm concerned that this application might be using a huge number of strings as keys.

If that cache lives forever then that's an issue (or not if the memory use is sufficiently low) whether you intern or not. In which case have the wrong approach to the right potential issue to investigate:

> I'd like to be able to monitor the amount of memory that the intern pool uses to store all these strings,

If they weren't interned but still lived forever in that cache, then if you stopped interning, you'd still be the same that amount of memory for the strings themselves, and the extra memory overhead of the interning wouldn't really be the issue.

There are a few reasons why one might want to intern a key, and not all of them are even bad (if the strings being interned are going to all appear regularly throughout the lifetime of the application then interning could even reduce memory use), but it seems here that the reason is to make sure that the key locked on is the same instance that another attempt to use the same string would use.

This might be thread safety at the wrong place, if `Add()` isn't thread-safe enough to guarantee that two simultaneous insertions of different keys can't put it into an invalid state (if `Add()` isn't explicitly thread-safe, then it does **not** make this guarantee).

If the cache is threadsafe, then this is likely extra thread safety for no good reason. Since `objToCache` has already been created and races will result in one being thrown away, it might be fine to let them race and have a brief period of two `objToCache` existing before one is collected. If not then `MemoryCache.AddOrGetExisting` or `ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd` deal with this issue much better than this.